# ヘッドホンで音を確認しながらの録音に関して

Tags: spresense

ヘッドホンで音を確認しながらSDに録音は可能ですか？
audio_throughが一番近いサンプルだと思ったのですが、うまく動作しませんでした。
（ヘッドホンからは何も鳴らない。）
audio_through-defconfigが無かったのでaudio_recorder-defconfigを参考に作成して
ビルドを通して実行しました。

Answer (score 1):

ソニーのSPRESENSEサポート担当です。
ご返事が遅くなり、大変申し訳ありません。

お問い合わせのヘッドホンで音を確認しながらの録音についてですが、
先日リリースのv1.2.0においてスケッチ例を追加いたしました。

Arduino IDE上で、
"ファイル" -> "スケッチ例" -> "Audio" -> "application" -> "recorder_with_rendering" 
を選択いただく事でスケッチ例を開くことができます。

また、Arduino環境ではアプリケーションの性能により書き込み
ファイルフォーマットはMP3のみになります。

今後ともSPRESENSEをどうぞよろしくお願いいたします。
SPRESENSEサポートチーム